# How to use a function variable in the R bracket notation?

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to calculate some simple ratios and use R's bracket notation to denote the baseline for the ratio.

Now I am struggling with defining a function that lets me parameterize the baseline.
I don't want to hardcode it, since I have a couple of those. And, I really don't understand what R is exactly doing and am very curious how to achieve the desired behavior.

Here some code based on example data:

```
data("singer", package = "lattice")

# this is what I want, but what currently doesn't work
my_ratio <- function(voice) {
  ddply(singer, ~ voice.part,
        transform,
        # how do I refer to the voice variable here?
        # it looks like it misunderstands it as column?
        ratio = height / mean(height[voice.part == voice]))
}

# this version works with a hardcoded voice part
my_ratio_hard <- function() {
  ddply(singer, ~ voice.part,
        transform,
        ratio = height / mean(height[voice.part == "Soprano 1"]))
}
```

Comment: and after asking the question, I found it :/ it is .(voice) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869005/how-can-i-use-variable-names-to-refer-to-data-frame-columns-with-ddply

Comment: Add that as an Answer and after 24 hours you can accept it if no other answer is provided which you like better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
my_ratio <- function(voice) {
  my_transform <- function(x) {
    transform(x, ratio = height / mean(height[voice.part == voice]))
  }
  ddply(singer, ~voice.part, my_transform)
}
```

Did you really only want to scale the rows matching `voice` and have `NaN` elsewhere (that's also what your hard-coded function does)?

A more compact version of the above:

```
my_ratio <- function(voice) {
  ddply(singer, ~voice.part, 
    function(x) transform(x, ratio = height/mean(height[voice.part == voice])))
}
```

and if you actually want to scale all the records (as your comment suggests):

```
my_ratio <- function(voice) {
  scale <- with(singer, mean(height[voice.part == voice]))
  ddply(singer, ~voice.part, 
    function(x) transform(x, ratio = height / scale))
}
```

Comment: The second, more compact version is what I as was looking for. Thanks! The singer example given here didn't actually work properly, right, but with my actual data it does what I wanted.

Comment: One more question, what is the explanation that wrapping it in a function works, but doing it directly does not work?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure! I assume it's some kind of scope issue. My guess is that it's related to the fact that `ddply(x, .formula, .fun, .args)` ends up putting `.args` as an argument to `.fun`. So, in your version, `voice` appears in the argument of a function, in my version its in the body. Others may be able to shed more light!

Comment: What I can say, is that inside `ddply` transform doesn't have access to the full `singer` data frame, just the cut up pieces, which is why the first of my compact versions ends up with `NaN`s.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not doing what I was looking for, but might be helpful in an other context.**

After asking the question I found [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869005/how-can-i-use-variable-names-to-refer-to-data-frame-columns-with-ddply):

To be able to refer to the variable, instead of a part of the data frame, object, etc. the dot-parentheses notation can be used: `.(voice)` is the solution. Thus, the proper function definition looks like:

```
my_ratio <- function(voice) {
  ddply(singer, ~ voice.part,
        transform,
        ratio = height / mean(height[voice.part == .(voice)]))
}
```

However, it does not result in the same behavior as using a literal string.

Comment: This is still not the solution. There is a subtle difference between a hardcode value and this form of quoting/deferred evaluation `.(voice)`. Now it only calculates the proper ratio for elements where the test succeeds, instead of using this subset and applying it to all elements(rows).